# IIS 10 Windows Server 2016 - Basic Authentication fails randomly

Tags: basic-authentication, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a rest api hosted on [IIS 10 Windows Server 2016] when I call the API from a [Rest Client] using [Basic Authentication] the request fails randomly.
The same request (API call) fails and succeed randomly without changing anything.

Comment: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: Basic Authentication is a significant security risk. As the user ID and password are passed over the network as clear text (it is base64 encoded, but base64 is a reversible encoding), the basic authentication scheme is not secure. HTTPS / TLS should be used in conjunction with basic authentication. Without these additional security enhancements, basic authentication should not be used to protect sensitive or valuable information.

Comment: You probably hit 401.3 which is completely irrelevant to Basic authentication (as that's authorization) https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: I found a difference between a succeeded request (URLInfoFromCache="false") and a failed request  (URLInfoFromCache="true") in the tracing logs

Comment: I found the trick. Inside the c# code a http call throw this 401 :) .